# Get the max value for given keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I have the following list:

```
information = [[U1, b1, 12], [U1, b2, 15], [U1, b3, 1], [U2, b1, 6], [U2, b2, 7], [U2, b3, 43]]
```

I want to return a dictionary from this which will give me the highest values for a pair of U and b, in the case of the given list it would be:

```
bestvalues = {(U1, b2): 15, (U2, b3): 43}
```

how do I achieve this with simple python code, can not import extra modules.

Comment: i don't understand. all your pairs have different U or b. How do you choose a pair of {U, b}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to sort (using [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), then group (using [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), then use [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) on each group.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

key = itemgetter(0)
bestvalues = {tuple(best[:2]): best[2] 
              for key, group in groupby(sorted(information, key=key), key=key)
              for best in (max(group, key=itemgetter(2)),)}
```

These are all standard-library modules.

Without any imports, you'd have to loop twice; first to group everything, then to find the maximum value for each group:

```
grouped = {}
for tup in information:
    grouped.setdefault(tup[0], []).append(tup)

bestvalues = {}
for group in grouped.itervalues():
    best = max(group, key=lambda g: g[2])
    bestvalues[tuple(best[:2])] = best[2]
```

Demo:

```
>>> information = [['U1', 'b1', 12], ['U1', 'b2', 15], ['U1', 'b3', 1], ['U2', 'b1', 6], ['U2', 'b2', 7], ['U2', 'b3', 43]]
>>> key = itemgetter(0)
>>> {tuple(best[:2]): best[2] 
...               for key, group in groupby(sorted(information, key=key), key=key)
...               for best in (max(group, key=itemgetter(2)),)}
{('U1', 'b2'): 15, ('U2', 'b3'): 43}
```

or without imports:

```
>>> grouped = {}
>>> for tup in information:
...     grouped.setdefault(tup[0], []).append(tup)
... 
>>> bestvalues = {}
>>> for group in grouped.itervalues():
...     best = max(group, key=lambda g: g[2])
...     bestvalues[tuple(best[:2])] = best[2]
... 
>>> bestvalues
{('U1', 'b2'): 15, ('U2', 'b3'): 43}
```

Comment: Typo - `operator`. Also, `key: max`:)

Comment: @SukritKalra: all fixed.

Comment: +1. I don't know if I should delete my answer now, you incorporated it better in your answer. :)

Comment: That's up to you! If the OP found your answer to be more helpful, it'd be foolish to delete yours.

Comment: Deleted. You gave a great answer. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters your answer is great however I think it is a bit misleading because I am looking for the best value, for any given "b". To clarify, the code should return max value for changing U without taking in account the b. Please refer to my final result given at bestvalues, that would clarify everything better than I write

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne: Updated; grouping on the first element, then finding the max on the last element to determine both the key and value.